# Bring from subconscious memory to conscious

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an English word that adequately describes the action of bringing the subconscious memory to the conscious?

For example, showing a watch to someone that makes them remember a forgotten event from long ago.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for "spark off", "trigger", or "jog one's memory".

According to [MacMillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/spark_1)

> to make someone feel, think of, or remember something
>
> Their growing reputation had sparked interest from other film-makers.
>
> Your article sparked off happy memories for me.

This link points to [some synonyms for cause someone to remember](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/to-cause-someone-to-remember)

Answer (score 0):

The word isn't of English origin, of course, but the closest sensation I can compare to what you're describing is that  of "deja vu." When one experiences deja vu, they have a very strong sensation of having experienced/been/done/seen this exact moment in time already. The expression is used commonly in the English language.

Answer (score 0):

**[recall](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/recall)**

> verb
>   [with object]
>   **1.1** Cause one to remember or think of.

*See also:*
Keim, "[Forgotten Memories Are Still in Your Brain](https://www.wired.com/2009/09/forgottenmemories/)," wired.com

**[remind](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/remind)** (ODO)

> verb
>   [with object]
>   **1** Cause (someone) to remember someone or something.
>   *[with object and direct speech]* *‘You had an accident,’ he reminded her*